# Assign variable read from file in Makefile recipe

Tags: python, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to do the following in a Makefile recipe. Get the server container-ip using a python script. Build the command to run within the docker container. Run the command in the docker container.

```
test:
    SIP=$(shell python ./scripts/script.py get-server-ip)
    CMD="iperf3 -c ${SIP} -p 33445"
    docker exec server ${CMD}
```

I get this

```
$ make test
SIP=172.17.0.6
CMD="iperf3 -c  -p 33445"
docker exec server 
"docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments.
See 'docker exec --help'.
```

Usage:  docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]

Run a command in a running container
make: *** [test] Error 1

Comment: Each line is executed in a seperate sub shell. Try put them all on one line connected by `&&`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with something like this.

```
SERVER_IP=$(shell python ./scripts/script.py get-server-ip); \
    SERVER_CMD="iperf3 -s -p ${PORT} -4 --logfile s.out"; \
    CLIENT_CMD="iperf3 -c $${SERVER_IP} -p ${PORT} -t 1000 -4 --logfile c.out"; \
    echo "Server Command: " $${SERVER_CMD}; \
    echo "Client Command: " $${CLIENT_CMD}; \
    docker exec -d server $${SERVER_CMD}; \
    docker exec -d client $${CLIENT_CMD};
```

This seems to work ok. Would love to hear if there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: I mean, why even write a makefile?  This is nothing more than a shell script embedded into a makefile by using the `$(shell ...)` make function.  Just write it as a plain shell script and it will be a lot simpler to understand and work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this. Here I used a [target-specific variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) assuming
the IP address is required only in this rule. `iperf_command` is defined as a variable
as the format looks rather fixed except the IP address which is injected by [`call` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html).

Also, as the rule doesn't seem to be supposed to produce the target as a file, I put [.PHONY target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) as well.

```
iperf_command = iperf3 -c $1 -p 33445

.PHONY: test
test: iperf_server_ip = $(shell python ./scripts/script.py get-server-ip)
test:
    docker exec server $(call iperf_command,$(iperf_server_ip))
```